# Using getter/setter for an array

Tags: c#

I'm trying to create a getter/setter for an array but I'm not sure how to write it. The class will have multiple properties that will need to be modified and accessed from another class. Here is an idea of what I'm trying to do:

```
class MyArrayClass {
    private double[] myArray = {1.1, 2.2};

    public double MyArray {
        get { return myArray[index]; }
        set { myArray[index] = value; }
    }
}

class AnotherClass {
    MyArrayClass mAC = new MyArrayClass();
    mAC.MyArray[1] = 3.3;
}
```

Now that code doesn't work but I hope it expresses what I'm trying to do. I was able to achieve what I wanted using the below code (which does work) however it only works for one property within that class.

```
class MyArrayClass {
    private double[] myArray = {1.1, 2.2};

    public double this[int index] {
        get { return myArray[index]; }
        set { myArray[index] = value; }
    }
}

class AnotherClass {
    MyArrayClass mAC = new MyArrayClass();
    mAC[1] = 3.3;
}
```

I'm also not sure how to define the values of different index positions without doing it multiple times, e.g.

```
mAC.MyArray[0] = 1.1;
mAC.MyArray[1] = 2.2;
```

As opposed to something such as:

```
mAC.MyArray[0, 1] = {1.1, 2.2};
```

Sorry if it's a mess but I hope it conveys what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: I'm using an array because I feel like it's most suitable for what I'm trying to achieve but I'd use List if it was more suitable.

Comment: Your second requirement (`arr[x,y] = {a, b}`) cannot be done - there's no built-in syntax sugar for that. Also, the syntax you proposed is actually used for accessing a [multidimensional array](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/2yd9wwz4.aspx). As for your first requirement, what exactly do you mean by "it only works for one property within that class."? What is it you need it to do? Could you provide some sample code of what you wish to do (even if it doesnt compile)?

Comment: Also, just so you know, the property you're using in your second code snippet is called an indexer. See more [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x16t2tx.aspx).

Comment: @dcastro - Yes I got the code from that page you linked. I'm trying to use the indexer but that way of doing it only seems to be able to handle one array per class because it uses `this`.

Comment: @tomofv You didn't provide much context, so I can't really judge what you're doing, but I get the feeling you should break your class in two. If your class has two internal arrays, and you want to expose both, it seems like the class is in charge of doing more than one task. Take a look at the [Single Responsibility Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).

Comment: For better context, my application is a game about different animals, and the class I'm referencing will hold properties for dogs. So one array will contain the heights of dogs, another will hold the weights. Different species of dogs will have their own index. So index 0 will always be German Shepherds, and index 1 will always be Pit bulls.

Comment: @tomofv If I may, I suggest having a class named `Dog`, with two properties `double Height` and `double Weight`, and then having an array `Dog[]`. That's the most natural and simplest way of modeling the scenario you described.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have several arrays, you need to expose several array-like *indexable* properties. Using your second `MyArrayClass` as an example, you can do it like this:

```
class MyTwoArrays {
    private MyArrayClass array1 = ...;
    private MyArrayClass array2 = ...;
    public MyArrayClass Array1 {
        get { return array1; }
    }
    public MyArrayClass Array2 {
        get { return array2; }
    }
}
```

Now you can use it like this:

```
MyTwoArrays two = new MyTwoArrays();
two.Array1[0] = 123.456;
two.Array2[0] = 789.432;
```

Comment: This seems to work but I don't understand why. Can you please tell me what this technique is called so I can read more about it? Thank you.

Comment: @tomofv This is a so-called [*Proxy Design Pattern*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern) (its other name is "surrogate pattern"). The idea is to present an object (in this case, `MyArrayClass`) as a stand-in for some other object (in this case, the array that it wraps).

Answer (score 0):

```
mAC.MyArray[0, 1] = {1.1, 2.2};
```

This is not the way it should be, it has to be done one by one. The way you're using would change it Two dimensional array, (somehow, it would be invalid, zero main elements and 1 element in each).

```
mAC.MyArray[0] = 1.1;
mAC.MyArray[1] = 2.2;
```

Is the valid way to set the arrays.

```
class MyArrayClass {
    private double[] myArray = {1.1, 2.2};

    public double this[int index] {
        get { return myArray[index]; }
        set { myArray[index] = value; }
    }
}

class AnotherClass {
    MyArrayClass mAC = new MyArrayClass();
    mAC[1] = 3.3;
}
```

Code works because if the valid way of doing the process because only in *this* case, you're passing an actual index number to the array to return the value from. In the first code block, there was no Index number, and the return was an `Array` object.

Comment: Yes I know that code works but my problem is having more than the one getter/setter for that class. Because I'm using `this` I can only do it to the one.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want your indexer to access 2 internal arrays representing heights and weights of animals.

```
class MyArrayClass {
    private double[] heights = {1.1, 2.2};
    private double[] weights = {1.1, 2.2};

    public double[] this[int index] { //Or Tuple<double ,double>
        get { return new double[] { heights[index], weights[index] }; }
        set { heights[index] = value[0]; weights[index] = value[1]; }
    }
}
```

If your intention is to access 2 numbers from 1 array, you can do that too.

```
class MyArrayClass {
    private double[] myArray = {1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4};

    public double[] this[int index] {
        get { return new double[] { myArray[index*2], myArray[index*2+1] }; }
        set { myArray[index*2] = value[0]; myArray[index*2+1] = value[1]; }
    }
}
```

This doesn't include checking the index or the argument (it can be null or have length < 2).

It might be more convenient in this case to have an Animal struct or something:

```
class MyArrayClass {
    private Animal[] animals = {new Animal(1.1, 1.1), new Animal(2.2, 2.2)}

    public Animal this[int index] {
        get { return animals[index]; }
        set { animals[index] = value; }
    }
}
```